# Advice on Creating a Step Indicator

Tags: android

I'm not exactly sure what to call these, but I'll refer to them as step indicators and have a couple of examples [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFXk5.jpg). How should I go about creating something similar? At first I thought about creating an array of ImageViews and using a counter variable to determine which indicator to highlight, but I'm not sure if this would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is called Page Indicator widget. There are many code implementation over internet. You can find one of theme here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

You can seach for more.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you want,you can look this project which can help you 
https://github.com/haikuowuya/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: did you forked only so that you could link to your own repo?